# Вывод данных из массива объектов typeScript

Tags: typescript, angular

Нужно вывести массив объектов в TypeScript. Есть массив
объектов:

```
products: Array<object> = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Пылесос Samsung', price: 2700, description: 
    'Мощность 750Вт'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Мультиварка Polaris', price: 2200, 
    description: 'С функцией скороварки'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Электрочайник Vitek', price: 750, 
    description: 'Очень быстро нагревает воду'}
];
```

Пробую получить доступ к этому объекту в том-же .ts-файле, сразу ошибку типа такого свойства(напр. name) не существует в типе object. Доступ делаю в методе - `this.products.name`.

В чём моя ошибка, помогите разобраться пожалуйста?

Comment: Замените `object` на `any` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а почему не на `Array<{ id: number; name: string; price: number; description?: string; }>`?

Comment: @nörbörnën конечно, просто с телефона проще `any` )

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, `products` - это массив. Следовательно, обратиться к `this.products.name` - нельзя, можно получить `name`, если обратиться к какому-то элементу массива, например по индексу.

```
this.products[0].name //обращение по нулевому индексу.
```

Во-вторых, лучше заранее вывести тип, чтобы было легче с ним работать.

```
type Product = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number
    description: string;
}

products: Array<Product> = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Пылесос Samsung', price: 2700, description: 
    'Мощность 750Вт'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Мультиварка Polaris', price: 2200, 
    description: 'С функцией скороварки'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Электрочайник Vitek', price: 750, 
    description: 'Очень быстро нагревает воду'}
];
```

P.S. Использовать `any` - не рекомендуется, потому что вы по сути убираете из Typescript типизацию, превращая его в Javascript.